# How to enable avresample when build ffmpeg from source?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am cross compiling ffmpeg for aarch64-none-linux-gnu platform.

I build this ffmpeg, is for my OpenCV built (VideoIO module requires ffmpeg).

After specifing my build-and-installed ffmpeg directories, build OpenCV, the cmake stage summary complains:

```
--   Video I/O:
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   YES (59.1.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (59.2.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (57.0.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (6.0.100)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

I would like to enable `avresample` for my ffmpeg build. However, I tried `--enable-avresample` but it says not-recognized.

How do I enable avresample during ffmpeg cross-compiling?

Comment: libavresample was [deprecated](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=c29038f3041a4080342b2e333c1967d136749c0f) in 2018-1, and [removed](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=420cedd49745b284c35d97b936b71ff79b43bdf7) from FFmpeg in 2021-4. Use libswresample instead. FFmpeg 4.4 is the final release that includes libavresample support.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I should't find `avresample` lib.

Finally solved opencv videoio module build, by specifying rpath in toolchain.cmake

References:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/19906